# Do you use Styrofoam balls to model your systems?

Tags: data-modeling

> [Objective-C]
>
> **Do you still use Styrofoam balls to model your systems, where each ball
>   represents a class?**
>
> **Tom Love:** We do, actually. We've also done a 3D animation version of
>   it, which we found to be nowhere near
>   as useful as the Styrofoam balls.
>   There's something about a physical,
>   conspicuous structure hanging from the
>   ceiling right in the middle of a
>   development project that's regularly
>   updated to provide not only the
>   structure of the system that you're
>   building, but also the current status
>   of each one of the classes.
>
> We've done it on 19 projects the last time I've counted. One of them was 1,856 classes, which is big - actually, probably bigger than it should be. It was a big commercial project, so it needed to be somewhat big.

[*Masterminds of Programming*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596515170)

---

It is the first time I've read or heard about using styrofoam balls to model classes.
Is that a commonly used technique? And, how does that sort of modeling help us to design better the system?

If you have any photos to share which can show us how the classes are represented it'd be great!

---

**Update:** So, it seems that the *material* most people use is the paper. Styrofoam balls are actually *oddballs*, not a commonly used technique.

Noticeable techniques:

- "paper plates and string" modeling, [NealB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896197/do-you-use-styrofoam-balls-to-model-your-systems/2930087#2930087)
- Post-it Notes on a whiteboard, [Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896197/do-you-use-styrofoam-balls-to-model-your-systems/2952616#2952616)
- [Class-Responsibility-Collaboration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class-responsibility-collaboration_card) cards, [duffymo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896197/do-you-use-styrofoam-balls-to-model-your-systems/2954476#2954476)
- Sheets of ruled paper taped to the wall, [AMissico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896197/do-you-use-styrofoam-balls-to-model-your-systems/2961998#2961998)

Thank you all for the very good answers.

Comment: What happens when the balls are too interconnected, or when they take up the whole room?

Comment: I can't imagine styrofoam balls being preferable to what I use - pipe cleaners and index cards with holes punched in them.

Comment: To elucidate a legacy system I work on, I've considered building a model out of mayonnaise and mud.

Comment: Maybe this speaks to how inane Objective-C is...you have to have balls to use it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a specific programming problem as defined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found a couple of styrofoam models for:

[Windows 95](http://lh4.ggpht.com/_kVBP7On28Fs/SzofNIe5VzI/AAAAAAAAA6s/QuoBE0H7jwo/s800/styrofoam_ball.jpg)

and

[Lotus Notes](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_YuyD-tLYbJc/SoIZwi9sUFI/AAAAAAAAAlY/OuzEW5WMXsY/s400/styrofoam2.jpg)

(if that helps)

Actually, here's a Tom Love case study that shows a couple of his [models](http://www.shoulderscorp.com/whitepapers/riskview-2.pdf).

> This model may represent the least
>   expensive CASE tool on the market --
>   materials cost $20.35.  It was more
>   useful than any CASE tools I have ever
>   used.
>
> We used it in three important ways.
>
> 1. It fixed the number of classes that we would deliver in the finished
>      application and we did not allow new
>      ones to be added, unless existing ones
>      could be removed.
> 2. It was a very useful way to publicly document which classes had
>      been code reviewed (blue ribbons) and
>      tested (green ribbons).
> 3. It helped everyone understand what was being built and how much time and
>      effort it takes to do testing,
>      documentation and code reviews.

**Edit: photo of object model**

[alt text http://img686.imageshack.us/img686/82/stryrofoamobjectmodel.jpg](http://img686.imageshack.us/img686/82/stryrofoamobjectmodel.jpg)

Comment: the pdf contains the kind of info I'm looking for! You should also add the photo of the object model in your answer, otherwise I'll do it :-) The other links you posted don't provide any hints and I don't understand why you *marked* them as Windows 95 and Lotus Notes. o_O

Comment: Love the Windows95 ball! lol

Comment: [I think this](http://blog.makezine.com/288471660_786a61454c.jpg) is a good example of a Styrofoam model for Linux. :D

Answer (score 15):

The styrofoam ball model appears to date back to the mid 1990's - a time when CASE (Computer Aided Systems Analysis)
systems were all the rage.

At that time CASE systems promised significant benefits but were dismally slow, 
buggy, unstable, overextended and downright awkward to use. Basically, long on potential but short on delivery.

I remember having a conversation with an analyst working on a different project from mine. Her team had
become so frustrated with their CASE system that they trashed it and resorted to "paper plates and string" 
modeling. They reserved a meeting room, removed all the furniture, and laid out their process model using labeled
paper plates with strings (representing data flows) connecting them. She claimed it was much more
useful than the CASE system it replaced.

I suspect that the styrofoam ball model had similar roots.

Using styrofoam balls or paper plates fostered design "buy-in". If a team
finds something to rally around it naturally creates a common design focus. It is simple, concrete and 
minimal - using it requires a lot
of face to face interaction and discussion. And that is where the value comes from. I suspect
if you brought a new person into the project and told them to bring themselves up-to-speed by
reviewing the "model" they would be "dead in the water". However, walk them through the
"model" and a real conversation would occur where all the required information need to
perform on the project would be imparted very quickly and efficiently.

Do I think styrofoam balls could become a sustainable modeling tool? No, I don't. They would be a real
pain to keep up to date in a changing environment. They convey little information.  There are better tools available
today. And most importantly, if the team you are working with don't "buy" it, and they
probably won't, it will look really stupid - kind of like a sports team mascot, a rallying point
only if the team "buys it".

Answer (score 12):

No, we don't do this. And in my 30-odd year history in the IT industry, I've *never* heard of anyone doing this.

The only way this could help you design better systems is by:

- keeping the class count down since it's hard to build the styrofoam model; and
- minimising changes, since updating it would be a serious pain in the rear end.

Other than those two dubious features, I can't see this as being very useful. I'd almost conclude it was some sort of prank. Far better to do some real work, I think.

Seriously, if we tried to model our application with styro coffee cups and straws, our bosses would be calling the men in white coats.

Comment: what if our bosses suggested us to try styro balls, should *we* call the men in white coats? Tom Love is a *boss*, isn't he? He must *know* something :-)

Comment: Hah, that's priceless. Does _your_ boss know anything? Most of mine haven't :-)

Comment: Appeal to authority is not a valid argument.

Answer (score 7):

Post-it Notes on a whiteboard seem to be popular in the circles I travel in.  Objects go on the Post-Its, and you rearrange them until you get your relationships the way you want em.

And then there are the Color Modeling people who use a 4-pack of colored Post-Its and assign an archetype to each color.  It doesn't sound like this is much of an improvement, but standing across a room looking at it, you can tell where there are missing features or unidentified objects in the system.

Answer (score 4):

There is one application to this that I think we tend to forget-- using tools to articulate an architecture comes naturally to us after years in the industry, but there are valuable, albeit less technically-minded, stakeholders who may not grasp vital concepts as readily.  It would sometimes be a lifesaver to point to a cluster of balls and say, "This is the Language Processing Model, and if I implement the feature you want, it will have consequences here, here, and here.  You can see that there are a lot of balls connected there".

Architects, be they designing buildings or systems, might rely on those tangible models to indoctrinate the check writers into the process.

Comment: +1 - A very, very good use for such a concept. I almost think it is worth implementing this just for this reason...

Comment: The user is thinking, "all you have to do is pull this stick out and push it into this ball. How hard can it be."

Answer (score 3):

And I thought that *UML* was useless.  The styrofoam ball model makes UML look positively elegant by comparison.

Ward Cunningham's CRC card idea is more useful, even cheaper, and still retains that tactile quality that Dr. Love was after.

I had never heard of the idea until I read this question.  It deserves an up vote for originality.  And the "Windows" and "Lotus Notes" pictures are priceless.

Answer (score 3):

Sheets of ruled paper taped to the wall, where each sheet is a component, class, entity, or whatever is needed. Everyone has a pencil.

Everyone can write on them "flushing" out the model during the design meetings. Such as, meeting notes, implemetation notes, new classes, removed classes, reasons why you do not have a particular class, and so on. After the design meeting, the principal designer takes them down and rewrite them, again "flushing" them out with pen in "rough-draft" versions. The designer can then make decisions based on the notes of each sheet, create new sheets for any additional components. Generate topics for next meeting, note any descrepancies, note any design / implementation details needed for coding, or whatever else they need to do.

Repeat the meetings until everyone is satisfied. Pencil is new stuff, pen is previous items. Once everyone is happy, the designer creates the working-draft, and posts where everyone can see and initial, in pen, their acceptance of the "working-draft".

Nothing is final. Pen versions are "latest" versions. Pencil versions are "work-in-progress" or "draft" versions.

Simple, fast, flexible, no wasting time on the computer, with high visiblity. Working man's Wiki.

Answer (score 1):

No. My team does not do this.

And I am badly tempted to mock with image macros. But I'm contemplating that the idea is silly enough that it is self-mocking.